# Decode json and display in table

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a HotUKDeals API which when using the URL bellow gives me some JSON.
Im trying to use PHP to display it in a table but if i try and use a loop to go through the JSON i get errors.

If i try and decode i get "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

So far I have this which i no gets the json and stores it in the variable .

I also have some JS which will go through JSON and put it in a table , but im having difficulties getting the JSON in the php variable into the JS.

```
Needed to remove code for work reasons !
```

Comment: Is the URL valid? I've tried to open that in my browser and it redirected me  onto another page.

Comment: @Voreny The URL is valid . It displayed JSON

Comment: You need to [`parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: Ok , but how do i get the json from php to jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the JSON into your jQuery code you'll have to use AJAX:

PHP file -

```
<?php 
    $tester = file_get_contents('http://api.hotukdeals.com/rest_api/v2/?key=d2c088ea340558b3b3517396963a341c&results_per_page=2&output=json');
    echo $tester;
?>
```

jQuery AJAX -

```
$.get( "hotukdeals.php", function( data ) {
    // now you can work with `data`
    var JSON = jQuery.parseJSON( data ); // it will be an object
    $.each(JSON.deals.items, function( index, value ) {
       console.log( value.title + ' ' + value.description );
    });
});
```

NOTE: The JSON that is returned has complex construction, so you will have to take care about how you extract during the loop and then place in the table.

Comment: so the javascript i have can go into the ajax?

Comment: You'll have to modify it to use object notation, like `JSON[i].title` @JohnyChew

Comment: iv modified the JavaScript to have the json var name , but  the output is blank . I also dont get any errors in teh console.

Comment: I think the var is empty

Comment: the JSON var i think

Comment: how do i get the json aobject to a string

Comment: It is a string when it comes from the PHP

Comment: The table is not filling its self . Also i tried this document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON;  and the div says [object JSON] in it

Comment: You have to parse and loop. It is possible that the JSON is not coming back in a format that you expect.

Comment: You can use a for loop, or jQuery's `$.each`

Comment: I tried this but didnt work -     
$.each(JSON, function(i, item) {
    alert(JSON[i].title);
});

Comment: That worked !  Now to get it to work with the js code for the table

Comment: one final question . How can i parse the json as UTF-8 to remove the weird characters?

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) @JohnyChew

Comment: @JohnyChew you may want to create another question for this. Make sure to be specific and provide sample code. I am tied up and don't want you to have to wait for an answer.